# PHP IF[FALSE/NULL/EMPTY] function

Tags: php

Since a year or so I had a function in all my projects called: `ifNot()`.

This function is somehow a derivated from the ternary operator:

```
public function ifNot( $item, $ifNot )
{
    if ( !$item ) {
        return $ifNot
    } else {
        return $item;
    }
}
// The var $foo twice
$var = ( $foo ) ? $foo : 'is empty or false =(';
// The var $foo once
$var = ifNot($foo, 'is empty or false =(');
```

In fact, Twig Template Engine use something like it:

```
{{ foo ? 'yes' : 'no' }}

{# as of Twig 1.12.0 #}
{{ foo ?: 'no' }} == {{ foo ? foo : 'no' }}
{{ foo ? 'yes' }} == {{ foo ? 'yes' : '' }}
```

The question is: There is a better/known approach for this function?

PS: SQL also has an `IFNULL()` =)

Comment: That's what we call an absolutely pointless function! It does something you could just as easily do without the extra function call, and it's not even easier to read ?

Comment: Yep, I asked this question looking for an alternative =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is essentially equivalent to [a variant of the conditional operator that was added in PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression ***expr1 ?: expr3*** returns *expr1* if *expr1* evaluates to **TRUE**, and *expr3* otherwise.

It may be a tiny bit faster to use the built-in approach if all your target environments are PHP 5.3 or greater, but I wouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: is there any difference between this behaviour and a simple `||`? I'm trying to understand why they added it to the language...

Comment: @Dave: `a || b` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, whereas `a ?: b` evaluates to either `a` or `b`. They do different things.

Comment: ah ok, got my JavaScript head on.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. There are a lot of posts about the ternary operator but the ones I read didn't point this variant.

Comment: @Axel: The conditional operator. It happens to be _a_ ternary operator.

Comment: In fact, "?:" isn't even a ternary operator here :)

Comment: @TML: Actually, yes it is. It's the _same_ operator (see the documentation) but with a zero-length second operand. You're right that it has two _functional_ operands.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm totally aware of what the documentation says; I'm also aware of the fact that at the implementation level, '?:' is entirely different from the ternary operator; look into zend_do_begin_qm_op/zend_do_qm_true/zend_do_qm_false (ternary) vs. zend_do_jmp_set/zend_do_jmp_set_else (binary '?:' operator).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your PHP is new enough (5.3.0 or newer). See the [PHP documentation on the ternary operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison.php)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

So while your code above *is* pretty awkward, there might be instances where you want a function version of this ternary operator (for example, to use as a [callable](http://php.net/language.types.callable) - in those cases, you could just roll with a closure:

`function($foo, $default) { return $foo ?: $default; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = ifNot($foo, 'is empty or false =(');
```

is the same as:

```
$var = $foo?:'is empty or false =(';
```

In normal PHP (>= version 5.3) too. Your ifNot function is completely superfluous.

Comment: [Only since PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right. But since some time I suppose that an user has at least 5.3 (as 5.2 is unsupported)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Someone who still uses PHP 5.2 and tries to develop new stuff there should eval("goto hell;"); and not receive an undefined label error...

Comment: Hey don't blame me, I'm just asking... And I use PHP 5.4 but haven't found enough information... Thanks for the answers BTW =)

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx I don't blame you, I only say that I doesn't make no sense to use such an `ifNot` function instead of `?:` ;-)

Comment: @bwoebi and that's the reason why I ask this question. Because _I don't want to use this function anymore_ So I looked for an alternative =)